# Will this work? Apex utility method to catch exceptions on DML statements

Tags: dmlexception, method, try-catch

So I am realizing that I should really put try/catch blocks around all the DML statements in my `after` triggers, but then I realized that maybe I can just write up a dynamic utility method that contains all the try/catch logic, and just call if from my trigger (or methods called within the `after` triggers).

Here is the method I came up with (first draft), I'm wondering if there are any fatal flaws...

```
public static void TryCatchDML(List<Sobject> recordsToDML, Map<Id, SObject> mapToTriggeredRecords, String operation) 
{
    // recordsToDML are the SObject records that are being updated
    // mapToTriggeredRecords: keys are IDs of the objects being updated, values are the SObject record in Trigger.new that should have an error added if caught
    // operation is insert, update, or delete
    try
    {
        if(operation == 'insert') insert recordsToDML;
        if(operation == 'update') update recordsToDML;
        if(operation == 'delete') delete recordsToDML;
    }
    catch(DMLException e)
    {
        for(Integer i = 0; i < e.getNumDML(); i++)
        {
            SObject errorRecord = recordsToDML[e.getDMLIndex(i)]; 
            Sobject triggeredRecord = mapToTriggeredRecords.get(errorRecord.Id);
            triggeredRecord.addError(e.getDMLMessage(i));
        }
    } catch(Exception e) 
    {
        System.debug('Exception type caught: ' + e.getTypeName());   
        System.debug('Message: ' + e.getMessage());   
        System.debug('Cause: ' + e.getCause());
        System.debug('Line number: ' + e.getLineNumber());   
        System.debug('Stack trace: ' + e.getStackTraceString());   
    }
}
```

Since `addError()` on a DML Error has to be added to an SObject that is within the `Trigger.new` list, I made it so that one of the arguments is a map of the ids of records being updated back to the triggered record.  So for example, here is how I'm calling the method in place of a simple `insert` statement:

(In this case I am updating a custom object abbreviated as `ofq`, within an Opportunity trigger)

```
if(ofqsToInsert.size() > 0)
{   
    Map<Id, Opportunity> ofqIDtoOppMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();
    for(Opp_for_Quota__c ofq : ofqsToInsert) ofqIDtoOppMap.put(ofq.id, newOppMap.get(ofq.id));
    GHCustomServices.TryCatchDML(ofqsToInsert, ofqIDtoOppMap, 'insert');
}
```

Comment: You might find some inspiration in [existing libraries](https://github.com/aalarson/DML/tree/master/src/classes) with the same goal.

Comment: I really highly recommend dropping the empty `catch(Exception e)` block.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Do you have any samples or blog post for [your DML library](https://github.com/aalarson/DML)?

Comment: @Oleksiy Not currently. I've been meaning to set up a blog. I hadn't even realized I didn't set up a `README`. About time to do so, methinks.

Comment: @AdrianLarson This would be great! It's sad that I see many times in SF community people are 'inventing the bicycle' for missing common utilities that can easily be produced and maintained as open source projects, can spread DRY and Clean Code practices, save tons of time for new and experienced devs.

Comment: @AdrianLarson your library looks like a great resource. I had no idea there was already an existing library for this, though the lack of documentation makes it a bit intimidating for a less experienced developer to implement. Where might one go about looking for other existing utility libraries like this?

Comment: I did just add some basic documentation. I'm not sure what other open source libraries are out there, but some google-fu might yield results.

Comment: Your map has an issue in `before insert` use case, should your utility be invoked in that scenario as there would be no IDs. Also, the `fflib` Unit of Work layer handles this in a centralized way

Comment: @cropredy thanks that's a great catch. Though considering all the above comments I'll probably end up scrapping this and using some other more robust library.